# Changing column values in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to replace all values (type: int) of a column in Spotfire, by String values like this :

```
old new    
1   a  
2   dog  
3   will  
1   a   
4   be   
2   dog
```

I'm a beginner in Spotfire, would anyone have an idea of how to do ?
Thx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Insert, select Calculated Column, then paste this along with the other cases into the expression box.

```
case when [old_col] = 1 then 'a'
when [old_col] = 2 then 'dog'
...
end
```